# Accept text with image in textBox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing Chat Application. so i want to acecpt string like Hi,mack How are you?[image: Smiley Image]
in text Box. I click on this image then i get this image but i don't know how i add this image in text-area.So how i add this image in text-box and also i want to print this image in div after i hit enter key.

First tell me How i will achieve this? and after that how i recognize whether accepted string contain any image or not?

Can anyone tell me??

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions,

1- Use a `wysiwyg` editor like [elrte](http://elrte.org/), so user can append any image.

2- Handle input string and replace common emoticons chars to `<img>` tag.

```
function chatMessage(message) {
  return message.replace(":)", "<img src='smileyicon.png' />")
}
```

**UPDATE:** You can find some nice plugins do that for you, like [this one](http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/).

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by text-box the  or the textarea , you can't show the image as i know .

in the second part "print this image in div after i hit enter key" you can replace the code of the image ":)" by   with javascript .

```
$("#chat_div").replace(":)","<img src='images/smil.gif' />");
```

Comment: To show image then how i will achieve this? any other way.

Comment: in the div of the conversation after replacing the ":D" , it will show up .

Comment: but in the textarea or the input ,i don't know , even facebook doesn't show the smells in the textarea .it shown after the msg sent in the div of the conversation .